The ratio $\Omega(n)/\omega(n)$ for a special set of integers
It is known that every positive integer can be expressed as  $n=s\cdot q $, where $s$ is a powerful number and $q$ a squarefree number, with
$(s,q)=1$. It is also known that the set of integers such that $s> q$ is of zero density.  Question: is the ratio $\frac{\Omega (n)}{\omega (n)}$ bounded from below with some positive constant $c> 1$ ,  for integers $n=s\cdot q $ with $s> q$ and $q> 1$? In other words, is there a positive constant $c$ such that inequality $\frac{\Omega (n)}{\omega (n)}\geq c>1$ is valid for all  such numbers? Here $\omega (n)$, $\Omega(n)$ denote the number and the total number of prime divisors of $n$.

If $\omega(s)=a\ge1$, $\omega(q)=b\ge1$, then $\frac{\Omega(n)}{\omega(n)}\ge\frac{2a+b}{a+b}\ge1$. Obviously, sharp. Take $q$ with many prime divisors and $s=p^2>q$ for prime $p$

This is obvious. Sorry, i forgot to add the condition  $c> 1$

I have completed my question with the condition $c> 1$.

The example of te4 shows that there is no such $c>1$. If $s=p^2>q$, where $p$ is a prime not dividing $q$, then $\Omega(n)/\omega(n)=(2+\omega(q))/(1+\omega(q))$, which is very close to $1$ when $\omega(q)$ is large.

Can we estimate the power of the set $\left{n\leq x,\frac{\Omega (n)}{\omega (n)}> 1+\varepsilon,\varepsilon > 0 \right}$ with $n=s\cdot q$,s>q, with fixed $\varepsilon$

I answered your question in the negative, so I suggest that you close it, and open a new entry for your new question. I also suggest that you explain (in your new post) what you mean by the "power of a set".

Revised question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483769/about-ratio-frac-omega-n-omega-n

What is the difference between "the number" and "the total number"?  With and without multiplicities?

@LSpice Yes. The notation is standard, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function
