About ratio $\frac{\Omega (n)}{\omega (n)}$
What is the asymptotic estimate of $\sharp\left\{n\leq x,\frac{\Omega (n)}{\omega (n)}> 1+\varepsilon  \right\}$, with fixed $\varepsilon > 0$, where $ n=s\cdot q$ ; $s$-a powerfull part of $n$ and $q$ a squarefree part of $n$, under the condition $s> q$ and $q> 1$ ?

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483757/the-ratio-omega-n-omegan-for-a-special-set-of-integers
